# Android 4.3 default browser: xmlDoc.evaluate throws INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM Xpath Exception 51

Tags: javascript, android, xml, xpath

I upgraded my phone to Android 4.3. When I use the default Android browser to bring up a page on my website that uses

```
xmlDoc.evaluate("//requestID", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
```

to select nodes, I get the following JavaScript error:

**INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM Xpath Exception 51**

As you can see, the xpath is correct.

I tried to bring up the following page from w3schools which has some code to select nodes from an XML document. But the results did not display. So I'm assuming that it is caused by the same error.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes

The code used to work before upgrading to 4.3. So it may be something specific to Android 4.3.

Did anybody run into the same error? Do you have suggestions on how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please always include example input and post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: I am seeing this also in Android 4.3 and it used to work in prior versions.  In my case I have an XML DOM loaded type [object Document] and calling document.evaluate('/rmc/description/text()',document)

Comment: document.evaluate("/html/body", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate gives the same error.

Comment: If I take the android tests, for example, external/webkit/LayoutTests/fast/xpath/text-nodes.html and run those tests on the device, they also give DOM Xpath Exception 51  -- seems document.evaluate is broken in 4.3 at least on the Samsung Galaxy Note II I have here.

Comment: @JensErat, please take a look at the link that I include in my comment. That serves as example input. It shows the code and the output.

Comment: Just some wild guessing: they might parse it as XHTML and require you to handle namespaces. Is `/` returning anything?

Comment: I am experiencing the same situation now. Having Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 version and Samsung Galaxy S III with Android 4.3 installed.

Comment: is your phone Samsung make?

Comment: @Abdul Did you have solved this problem?  what is the workaround for this issue ?

Comment: @MartinC How did you solve this problem ? I had posted to Samsung Developer Forum, but nobody give me a response.

Comment: Refer to http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=253999

Answer (score 2):

I confirm this bug caused by certain Samsung devices. A workaround to this problem will be using another xpath implementation such that we can avoid using Samsung's faulty one.

I tried XPathJS (https://github.com/andrejpavlovic/xpathjs) and the xpath problem seemed to be solved.

Simply include the js, then do:

```
// bind XPath methods to document and window objects
// NOTE: This will overwrite native XPath implementation if it exists
XPathJS.bindDomLevel3XPath();
```

No other code changes required.

Answer (score 1):

it's a Samsung bug, we have recreated it on Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Note 10.1 2014. 
You have to use standard xpath parser and not to load the DOM into memory (Samsung).

Comment: @Samuel.Cai Please refer to my answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static String SAMSUNG_MANUFACTURER = "samsung";
private final static String PLATFORM_TAG = "yourPlatform";
private final static String EXCLUDE_XPATH = "exclude-xpath";

//This part adds a custom header in order to exclude the xpath engine.
//This is due to a bug on some Samsung devices, Android version 4.3 where the webkit
//engine falsy replies compatibility with xpath. Adding this param to the useragent
//makes Mootools-1.11 use the normal xpath parser instead.

WebView mBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==BUILD_SDK_INT_4_3&&SAMSUNG_MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER))
{
String userAgent = mBrowser.getSettings().getUserAgentString()+", "+PLATFORM_TAG+"/"+EXCLUDE_XPATH;
mBrowser.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
}
```